# Abstract Class Inheritance Confusion

Tags: c#, oop

I have a D class inherits from C abstract class and writing to console related message. I expect to see "D" on my console window but it writes "B". I think virtual keyword in C class breaks the rule. I didn't understand why. Can anyone explain?

```
  class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A obj = new D();
        obj.Write();
        Console.Read();
    }
}

public abstract class A
{
    public virtual void Write()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A");
    }
}

public abstract class B : A
{
    public override void Write()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B");
    }
}

public abstract class C : B
{
    public virtual void Write()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("C");
    }
}

public class D : C
{
    public override void Write()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("D");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your compiler already does a pretty good job here if you listen to it:

```
warning CS0114:

'C.Write()' hides inherited member 'B.Write()'.
```

> To make the current member override that implementation, add the **override** keyword.
>
> Otherwise add the **new** keyword.

The fact that you used `virtual` instead of `override` on C will result in the default behaviour of `new` for this method, breaking the inheritance chain.

Comment: If it was hided why `B.Write` was executed?

Comment: Because the type you called it on was an `A`. If you make your variable a `D` or `C` your method writing "D" will be called.

Comment: Ok, then why `A.Write` execute `B.Write`, why not "A"?

Comment: Because the instance is a D. Which makes it an A, a B, a C and a D. Calling it through an A, the compiler knows B has an improved version of the Write method. C and D do not. Because it's not A's Write method, but a *new* one. Therefor the compiler calls the best method for A.Write it can find: B.Write.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `C` does not override the function from class `A`. The compiler gives you a warning the the `new` keyword is required. If you also use `override` in class `C`, it works like you expected.

Or if you replace `A obj = new D();` with `D obj = new D();`, you would get the same result.